# Images in runnable jar are not working - NullPointer is thrown

Tags: image, jar, executable

I've seen this question all over this website. And I've read almost every response. I feel like I'm doing exactly what is required, but I just can't get it to work! I'm trying to package some images into a Runnable Jar so that my program is self-contained. When I run the code in Eclipse, it works as intended. But when I use the executable Jar, the program will not launch. It gives me a NullPointerException on the line where I create the image. The files are in a folder called Resources in the source folder of the project. Here is the code. It is incomplete because this is just a test program that I've been trying to get working.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class testgui extends JFrame{
private static JLabel label = new JLabel();
private static testgui gui = new testgui();
private static ArrayList<ImageIcon> sprites;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sprites = getImages();
    BufferedImage backgroundImage;
    try {
        backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new testgui().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/runescapemap.png"));
        gui.setContentPane(gui.new ImagePanel(backgroundImage));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gui.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    label.setIcon(sprites.get(0));
    gui.add(label);
    gui.setSize(1000,900);
    gui.setVisible(true);
}

private static ArrayList<ImageIcon> getImages(){
    ImageIcon autoTalkerLogo = new ImageIcon(new testgui().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/autotalker-logo.png"));
    ImageIcon meterNormal = new ImageIcon(new testgui().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/meter.png"));
    ImageIcon meterSafe = new ImageIcon(new testgui().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/meter-safe.png"));
    ImageIcon meterNotSafe = new ImageIcon(new         testgui().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Resources/meter-notsafe.png"));
    ArrayList<ImageIcon> sprites = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
    sprites.add(autoTalkerLogo);
    sprites.add(meterNormal);
    sprites.add(meterSafe);
    sprites.add(meterNotSafe);
    return sprites;
}

class ImagePanel extends JComponent {
    private Image backgroundImage;
    public ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.backgroundImage = image;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the folder is genuinely called `Resources` rather than `resources`, that could be the problem. While the Windows file system is case-insensitive, jar files aren't.

Try

```
...getResource("Resources/runescapemap.png")
```

I note that your later calls to `getResource` *do* use `Resources` rather than `resources`.

Of course, it could be the other way round - maybe your folder is actually `resources`, and it's the first call that's okay and the other four should use `resources`. Either way, it's unlikely that *both* are correct...

Comment: You were right! "r" in "resources" needed to be capitalized. The reason that my capitalization was inconsistent was because I was trying to change things in order to get it working. I must have developed some inconstantsy through my changes.